# how to set auto commit false in spring junits

Tags: spring, junit

I want set auto commit false in spring junits.
I am testing save methods and they are persisting in DB. 
Help me how to disable commit in spring junits.

I used the following codes

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
```

and

```
"< property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />"
```

Still test data is saving in DB.

Comment: Which database system? If mysql, which storageengine?

Comment: It is Oracle. and it is working with above code after clean build